# Install client certificate in PHP application

Tags: php, jira, testlink

I'm trying to connect testlink with JIRA but I'm having problems with the JIRA certificate. I configure testlink to connect to JIRA but this error appear:

> SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed - in /opt/testlink-1.9.14-2/apps/testlink/htdocs/lib/issuetrackerintegration/jirasoapInterface.class.php - Line 197

I don't know anything about PHP but I need this application to manage test plans. testlink are deployed at httpd2.

At java the certificate from JIRA has to be added to the jdk cacerts, but in php where?

Comment: Are you hosting Jira on your servers or using their cloud?

Comment: I have everything in my platform, JIRA are serving with ssl, thats why testlink can't connect.